# How to create a layered map in a mobile appliaction

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, java-me

I have seen a mobile application named [Locago](http://www.locago.com/site/Index) on getjar.com. It has a map with many layers, for example, a layer for Wikipedia.

How to create a map with layers in a [J2ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition) mobile application?